# Do "OneShot" systemd services not related to boot/shutdown have a timeout by default?

Tags: systemd

Do "OneShot" systemd services not related to boot/shutdown have a timeout by default ?

If it is the case, how one could verify the current default value used by their distro ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  `type=oneshot` services do not honor `TimeoutStartSec` by default.

From [systemd.service(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)

> TimeoutStartSec=
>
> Configures the time to wait for start-up. If a daemon service does not signal start-up completion within the configured time, the service will be considered failed and will be shut down again. Takes a unit-less value in seconds, or a time span value such as "5min 20s". Pass "infinity" to disable the timeout logic. Defaults to DefaultTimeoutStartSec= from the manager configuration file, **except when Type=oneshot is used, in which case the timeout is disabled by default** (see systemd-system.conf(5)).

It reasons ...

> Behavior of oneshot is similar to simple; however, it is expected that the process has to exit before systemd starts follow-up units. RemainAfterExit= is particularly useful for this type of service. This is the implied default if neither Type= nor ExecStart= are specified.

... which means it will execute the oneshote command(s) and when (if) the process(es) exit(s) then the service will be marked active if `RemainAfterExit` is true.  If, for some reason, the process never exits then that could be a problem and cause to use another type which does honor `TimeoutStartSec` by default, such as `type=simple`.  Or, you can explicitly set `TimeoutStartSec` for `type=oneshot` services.

Comment: The `man` description only means that by default, `TimeoutStartSec` is disabled for `oneshot` services. This does not mean it is not respected when it is set.

Comment: Thanks.  Corrected.